# jgrapht-jdk1.6 "HelloJGraphT.java" compilation problem

Tags: javac, jgrapht

JGraphT package includes some examples to experiment oneself. HelloJGraphT.java is one of them. I can run it, without any error, in Netbeans6.0.1. But, when i use dos command prompt in the following way:

> javac -cp jgrapht-jdk1.6.jar HelloJGraphT.java

it compiles. But, if i run it using:

> java HelloJGraphT

it gives the following errors:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jgrapht/Graph
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jgrapht.Graph
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(Unknown Source)

Any clue?

I'm using jdk 1.6

Answer (score 1):

You need to import the JGraphT library to your project.